# Can't upload file using XAMPP

Tags: php, upload, xampp, photo

I have to create a CMS for a webstore for a webscript unit i'm taking. I have to upload a photo of the product but i keep getting and error when i try to upload. I search it a lot and tried a lot of things, i changed the folder to read & write, i did the 'chmod -R 777...', nothing. I'm starting to think the problem is with my code. I appreciate all help, thanks!

I always this error: Warning: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

```
<?php

    $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'ezcart';

    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {

        die("Could not connect to the database: " . $conn->connect_error);

    }

    $name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
    $type = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];

    if (isset($name)) {

        if(($type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/jpg' || $type = 'image/png') && ($size <= 3145728)) {

            $path = 'prod_photos/';

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$name)) {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO product (prodCat, prodDes, prodNam, prodPho, prodPri, prodSto, prodSup) VALUES ('$_POST[prodCat]', '$_POST[prodDes]', '$_POST[prodNam]', '$name', '$_POST[prodPri]', '$_POST[prodSto]', '$_POST[prodSup]')";

                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

                    echo '<span>Product added sucessfully.</span>';

                }

            }

        }

        else {

            echo '<span>Please choose a valid photo.</span>';

        }

    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: What about your form, does it contain a POST method and a valid enctype?

Comment: Yes, they are allright.

Comment: Check to see what your upload max settings are and that your tmp folder isn't full. Plus, Google your error message. Too many reasons why it could fail.

Comment: The upload max setting is ok, i googled it and i cant really find something useful, i tried the main awnsers to it.

Comment: Are you on Windows or UNIX? See also chown http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

Comment: Also check your tmp setting in php.ini `upload_tmp_dir = /home/public_html/tmp` see if that folder can be written to (as an example). Again, too many possible reasons/answers found on Google as to why it's failing and we could be commenting forever. Ownership and permissions on /tmp - try chmod 775 /tmp

Comment: I checked that yesterday, it seems fine. file_upload=on, upload_tmp_dir="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/" and upload_max_filesize=128M and the folder is writable.

Comment: If you made any changes to system files without restarting services/rebooting, then those won't take effect until you do.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `php.ini` and look for the `'upload_tmp_dir'` option.

After that, check the permission of your tmp dir, and try to chmod it again.

If you want to know what upload_tmp_dir your server is using, you can simply use this:

```
die(ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ? ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') : sys_get_temp_dir());
```